# Why doesn't the default Yeoman app module need an empty array for dependencies injection?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, module, yeoman

I know this feels like a silly question but it really bothers me.  I've learned when declaring a module in angular, that one must put an empty array, regardless of there being a dependency needed.

EX: (basic angular added app)

```
angular.module('ang6App', [])
```

However in Yeoman (the angular generator) this array[] is omitted; moreover, it crashes the app, if added.

EX: (yeoman angular generator)

```
angular.module("ang6App")
```

What is this witchcraft in Yeoman?  is there a difference between the modules implementations?  How do I reproduce this in my a custom scaffolds of an a angular application?

Comment: have you searched for all locations where .module is used? what is the error message you get?

Comment: ok so the app.js declares dependencies... So I guess if if the module is called again it inherits that declaration?

Comment: Yes, you can only have one place that defines dependencies (the array) for each module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `module()` method has different meanings depending on the numbers of arguments you pass.

To create a module:

```
angular.module('moduleName', []); // creates a module with the name 'moduleName'
```

To retrieve an existing module, omit the second parameter:

```
angular.module('module'); // will return the module 'moduleName' created in the previous command
```

Hope that helps!